# Compare Iterated link text to another list link elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to compare list of links if the text matched another sets of links and add a class active to my first sets of links

```
var collectionTag = $('.collection-filter-tag li.active a').text();
var collectionNav = $('.navigation-list li a').text();

$('.navigation-list li a').each(function() {
  var collectionTextTag = $(this).text();
    if(collectionTextTag == collectionTag){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    console.log(collectionTextTag);

  });
```

Comment: `text` is a String, not a jQuery object.  `is()` only works on jQuery objects.  `F12` to open your developer tools, go to the Console tab, and make sure there are no errors.  If there are errors, fix them.

Comment: Thanks i update the code on the part where im stuck. Thanks

Comment: "loop item text" ?

Comment: the text value of the link <ul><li><a>test</a></li></ul> i need to compare "test"

Comment: So `collectionTag === collectionTextTag`